# VBA to copy Excel cells to Word with certain formatting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have cells in Column C with tool tips for code to apply certain formatting while copying from Excel to Word. In Column C there is for example word "title" = cell C14. My code should copy cell B14 to Word with formatting of "Heading 1". Then I have "par" in cell C16 code should copy B16 with formatting of "Normal" etc.

I came up with this solution but it is not copying anything. I think the problem is with `.TypeText Text:=.Range(0, -1).Text`? I have been trying different variants with no success.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub main()


        Dim objWord As Object
        Dim objDoc As Object
        Dim objSelection As Object
        Dim Cell as Range


        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") '<--| get a new instance of Word
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add '<--| add a new Word document
        objWord.Visible = True
        Set objSelection = objDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection '<--| get new Word document 'Selection' object

        With objSelection '<--| reference 'Selection' object

    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offer Letter").Range("C1", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offer Letter").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         Select Case LCase(cell.Value)
        Case "title"
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .Style = objWord.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
                    .TypeText Text:=.Range(0, -1).Text
            Case "par"
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .Style = objWord.ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
                    .TypeText Text:=.Range(0, -1).Text
          End Select
       Next cell

        End With

        objDoc.SaveAs2 ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("Other Data").Range("AN2").Value & ", " & Sheets("Other Data").Range("AN7").Value & "_" & Sheets("Other Data").Range("AN8").Value & "_" & Sheets("Other Data").Range("AX2").Value & ".docx" '<--| save your word document

        objWord.Quit '<--| quit Word
        Set objWord = Nothing '<--| release object variable
    End Sub
```

Comment: `.TypeText Text:=.Range(0, 0).Text`: Should `Range` here refer to the start of the Word document or to a `Range` in Excel? These lines of code are telling Word VBA to type in the content of the zero position in `objSelection`. The zero position will always be "nothing"...

Comment: `.TypeText Text:=.Range(0, -1).Text` This should get value from Excel one cell left to Column C (if there is value "title" or "par") and paste it to Word with formatting of "Normal" or "Heading 1" according to Case.

Comment: Because `With` is referring to `objSelection` the reference to `.Range(0, -1)` needs to be "spelled out" with the full information to "locate" it in Excel. Would that be `cell.Range(0,-1)` ?

Comment: Still getting an error 1004 on `.TypeText Text:=cell.Range(0, -1).Text`. This task is quite time consuming.

Comment: Should this `.Range(0, -1).Text` be `cell.offset(0,-1).text` ?

Comment: `cell.offset(0,-1).text` worked!